# Symfony2.8 upgraded to symfony3.4, Logger has an error

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-3.4

```
use Psr\Log\LoggerInterface;

class TestController extends Controller
{
    public function indexAction(Request $request, LoggerInterface $logger)
    {
        $logger->info('this is a Logger info!');
        return new Response('123456');
    }
}
```

> requires that you provide a value for the "$logger" argument. Either
>   the argument is nullable and no null value has been provided, no
>   default value has been provided or because there is a non optional
>   argument after this one. in
>   /home/Workspaces/rlife_api/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/Controller/ArgumentResolver.php:78

Ask how to solve this problem???

Comment: I'm guessing you'll need to go through https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/3.4/UPGRADE-3.{0,1,2,3,4}.md and check for this (and other possible issues that may come up).

Comment: I have read the documentation and there is no solution. The main problem is to use dependency injection instead of container service

Comment: The "logger" service is private, getting it from the container is deprecated since Symfony 3.2 and will fail in 4.0. You should either make the service public, or stop using the container directly and use dependency inject
ion instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a solution and is to [tag the cotnrollers](https://symfony.com/doc/current/controller.html#controller-accessing-services) and [enable the autowire](https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container/autowiring.html) in order to pass the deps in the right way

Comment: Unfortunately the links are dead